# Using a loop to validate entries on Excel userform?

Tags: excel, vba

Updated*
I have 20 Text boxes labeled as `T_0_Date(1-20)`, the user can freely enter text but I need to validate the entries as dates before allowing the remainder of the script to execute.  For example `09-Dec-16` is an expected entry, if the user entered `Waffle`, I need the script to catch it.  I can write the same code 20 times, but it would look ugly.  So just trying to accomplish this with a loop.

First post, so I apologize for any mistakes in advance.
I am building a user form that has 20 fields that need to be validated as dates.  I am trying to find a way to use a loop to accomplish this to keep my code from being ugly.  I was trying:

```
For q = 1 To 20
tb9 = T_0_DATE(q).Value
If Err And tb9 <> 0 Then MsgBox "Error Message"
Next q
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Give a sample of your data and try to rephrase your question. What exactly needs to be validated?

Comment: @ Moacir Post updated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validation for Userform to check for empty controls, using loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370769/validation-for-userform-to-check-for-empty-controls-using-loops) and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Dim cCont As Control

        For Each cCont In Me.Controls
            If TypeName(cCont) = "TextBox" Then
                'more checks and other code
            End If
        Next cCont
```

this is how you looop through controls in a user form. you're welcome :)